# How to resolve Jena StmIterator import

Tags: java, eclipse, jena

I'am new on Jena.

I followed the starting tutorial here: https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html

However, I get error on eclipse. Eclipse can't resolve the import of "StmIterator".

> The type org.apache.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator cannot be resolved.
>   It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

Although the build path seems to be correct.

I'm working with Jena 3.8.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Make sure the build path is correct and Eclipse shows the correct Jena jars (all of them) for the project.  Check jena-core jar is there.

Comment: Yes I checked Jena-Core, and all classes are included. However, only StmIterator.class presents an anomaly. Contrary to other classes, eclispe is not able to show its content (variables and methods).
I returned to the version 2.11, and the content of StmIterator.class is visible there.
Seems to be a bug in the 3.8 version.

Comment: It is either bug of Eclipse or hands, but not Jena. Don't you see that this error cannot be related to the particular api? May you just google "It is indirectly referenced from required .class files."? Imho, Eclipse is not suitable to those, who are not a guru in java.

Comment: Here is what i've done:
1/-downloading Jena 3.8 from Jena web site.
2/-unzipping the file on C:\
3/-creating a Java project
4/-I gone to the project "properties/Java build path"
5/-Selected "Add Library/User Library" and first created the Jena 3.8 Lib (and added all the .Jar files), next i've added the created Lib to the Build Path.
--
Next, in the package explorer to visualize the "Jena-core-3.8.jar", I can localize the "StmIterator.class", but it seems to be empty, contrary to ohter classes.
But, as I stated before, the content of "StmIterator.class" is present with Jena 2.11.

Comment: Solution:
The problem has been solved by migrating from Eclipse Indigo to Eclipse Juno.
it was intriguing.
Thank to ssz and AndyS

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
The problem has been solved by migrating from Eclipse Indigo (that I used at the beginning) to Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Actually, the problem is more likely in local Eclipse caches. 
Reinstalling that Indigo should also solve that problem, but it is always better to use up-to-date software and libs.